# Heroku router closing persistent http/1.1 connection requests?

Tags: http, heroku

I have a application hosted on Heroku, and it seems to be adding a Connection:close to the response header of a HTTP/1.1 connection request, and not allowing us to re-use a persistent HTTP/1.1 connection. This works for other apps I have on Heroku, but I can't figure out why it would do this for this app. Any clues?

So if I attempt to test with curl for example,

```
curl -v "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/posts/trending"  "http://myapp.com/api/posts/trending"
* Connected to myapp.herokuapp.com () port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/posts/trending HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: myapp.herokuapp.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: close
< Date: Mon, 09 Mar 2015 20:54:15 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
* Server Jetty(9.2.7.v20150116) is not blacklisted
< Server: Jetty(9.2.7.v20150116)
< Via: 1.1 vegur

...response...
* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here, according to Heroku Support, it is known limitation of the Heroku router, since Jetty doesn't send Connection: keep-alive in the response of HTTP/1.1 request by design. No suggested workarounds at this time.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... Did you finally find a solution?